# How do I interpret the output of the filefrag command?

Tags: filesystem

I have a dump file in my system that has confidential data in it. I tried using the `filefrag` command to open it. The output is:

```
root@sateesh935-SVE15115ENB:/home/sateesh935/Desktop/g3# filefrag -v dump

Filesystem type is: ef53

File size of dump is 267894784 (65404 blocks, blocksize 4096)

ext logical physical expected length flags
0     0     3328000         6144
1    6144   3500032       3334144    32768
2    38912  3532800        26492      eof
dump: 2 extents found
```

What does the above output indicate? How can I get the data from the dump file?

I will tell you the whole procedure which I have done.

1. First I got the `dump.enc` file.
2. To extract the the data from that I used the following command.

   ```
   openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in dump.enc -out dumpL
   ```

   and it is encrypted by the AES-256 for that I have used a key and I extracted the file.
3. Now I got the dumpL file in which some data is there.
4. But I don't know how to see the data in that file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a file called dump. Its split in two parts. [As per the manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/filefrag) `filefrag reports on how badly fragmented a particular file might be. It makes allowances for indirect blocks for ext2 and ext3 filesystems, but can be used on files for any filesystem.`. If you're expecting it to do something else, you're doing it wrong.

Of course without know what or where 'dump' is from, we can't tell very much. EF53 is a 'magic' number, that refers to EXT2/3 and 4 and is the filesystem the harddrive dump is on is using. You cannot extract any other useful information other than that.

Comment: Then how to view data in that particular file?

Comment: Ok. I will tell you the whole procedure which I have Done.